# styled-components and TS2769: No overload matches this call

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I am trying to use `styled-components` to style my own component, but it has been a while since I used this library. Re-reading the documentation, I don't actually recall using it like this to style my own component, but there we go.

I am using `style-components` version 5.3.5 and `react` version 18.1.0.

My `App.tsx` looks like this:

```
const AppComponent = () => (
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <Calculator></Calculator>
  </ThemeProvider>
);

const App = styled(AppComponent)`
  background-color: ${props => props.theme.primaryColor};
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
`;

export default App;
```

and my `Calculator.tsx` looks like this:

```
const CalculatorComponent = ({className}) => (
  <div className={className}>This is a calculator</div>
);

export const Calculator = styled(CalculatorComponent)`
  background-color: ${props => props.theme.primaryColor};
`;
```

Now, `App.tsx` appears to have trouble compiling, generating this error:

> ```
> Property 'className' is missing in type '{}' but required in type '{ className: any; }'.
> 6  | const AppComponent = () => (
> 7  |   <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
> 8  |     <Calculator></Calculator>
>    |      ^^^^^^^^^^
> 9  |   </ThemeProvider>
> 10 | );
> ```

I can't understand this. I am following [the documentation about styling your own component](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#styling-any-component), but there is no hint there as to what I might be doing wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
 export const Calculator = ({className}) => 
    (<CalculatorStyled className={className}>
    This is a calculator
    </CalculatorStyled>);

export const CalculatorStyled = styled.div`
  background-color: ${props => props.theme.primaryColor};
`;
```

In your case, this is needed and it will work. If you want to do with other system you need pass children element as well. That's why its throws error

Comment: I tried this, it gave rise to the same error. I am thinking my tsconfig needs adjusting. I preferred the look of your solution to my own, but unfortunately yours doesn't work for me,

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. I am now doing this:

```
const CalculatorComponent = ({...rest}) => (
  <div {...rest}>This is a calculator</div>
);

export const Calculator = styled(CalculatorComponent)`
  background-color: ${props => props.theme.primaryColor};
`;
```